# Using the picture write down all values of $\sqrt[12]{z}$ and then find the main value of that number $z$.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

**Problem: Let $1+i\sqrt 3$ be one root of $\sqrt[12]{z}$. Display that number in complex plane and then, in that plane, display other roots of number $\sqrt[12]{z}$. Using the picture write down all values of $\sqrt[12]{z}$ and then find the main value of that root.**

My idea:

Since I need to find $\sqrt[12]{z}$, I will have dodecagon. One root is $1+i\sqrt 3$, so one vertex is in $(1,\sqrt 3)$.  That also means that my angle, for given vector, is $\ {\frac \pi3}$, and $|(1+i\sqrt 3)|=2$.

To get other roots, should I "move" given one by $\ {\frac \pi6}$?
For example:
$$2\,\,\,e^{\ {\frac \pi3}i}\,\,\,  e^{\ {\frac \pi 6}ki}$$ where $k=\overline{1,11}$ and $1+i\sqrt 3$=$2\,e^{\ {\frac \pi3}i}$?

Is the main value number $2^{12}$ with main angle $0$?
This is the picture I get when I calculate $\sqrt[12]{2^{12}}$. It seems okay, I guess.

[image]

My question is, is this way of solving this problem correct because it asks me to write down values using the picture only and, as you can see, I have done some calculation. Even if I can see where my roots will be placed, I still had to find the angle. I hope my question is clear.

Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this looks fine (aside from the fact that the principal 12-th root is certainly not $2^{12} = 4,096$ as you've written) and I think this is what they meant by telling you to "use the picture."

Comment: Ah, they are asking for main value of root. That is two? I will edit my question, because I did not know how to translate it correctly.